# How to properly use the create table in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

This is a conceptual question, I am a developer who is familiar with Mongo & Postgres. In both of these DMS, you never have to create a table before using it. I don't really know how it works under the table but I create my Schema's in Mongo or my classes in Postgres (I use SQLAlchemy ORM) defining the structure of my different tables.

With DynamoDB I understand I can do the same but before adding an item/column into the table I need to check if the table is created? I don't really get how that works. Do I just create the tables the first time I create my db instance and if I add more tables I just create them once??

I understand the reasoning behind DynamoDB needing me to create the tables explicitly because they will allocate a certain amount of space in anticipation of the items that will be stored there but I have looked around and not really found a best practice or advice on when I should be creating new tables in DynamoDB?

Comment: DynamoDB doesn’t expose any sort of DB instances. Do you have any specific use cases in mind for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it this way: the DynamoDB table is the same as your Postgres database, not your Postgres tables. It's a piece of infrastructure that your service depends on, so you need to create the table at the same time you would create your Postgres database.

Also be sure to understand that unless you're doing some very, very complex thing, dynamoDb is intended to be used with 1 table per service. So if you're thinking "I need 4 tables", I'd suggest looking at this great [aws video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k).

Comment: Half way through the video but this was exactly what I was looking for, it answers my question perfectly thank you!